# Can git permanently ignore a remote branch?

Tags: git, branch

I'm using the Pages feature of GitHub. This works by putting the published HTML in a branch called `gh-pages`. I have two separate working directories, one for the project itself and one for the HTML docs.

In the former, I want to completely ignore the `gh-pages` branch, as it's an unrelated line of work and I don't want it to clutter up my various commit visualizations.

That is, what I have is:

```
$ git remote show origin
* remote origin
  Fetch URL: git@github.com:reidpr/quac.git
  Push  URL: git@github.com:reidpr/quac.git
  HEAD branch: master
  Remote branches:
    bar              tracked
    foo              tracked
    gh-pages         tracked
    master           tracked
  Local branches configured for 'git pull':
    master    merges with remote master
  Local refs configured for 'git push':
    master    pushes to master    (up to date)
```

and what I want is something like:

```
$ git remote show origin
  [...]
  Remote branches:
    bar              tracked
    foo              tracked
    gh-pages         ignored
    master           tracked
  [...]
```

Note there are several branches that I *do* want to track, and just one that I don't. I want to specify the latter, not the former.

I can delete the local references to `origin/gh-pages`, but then it comes back next time I `git fetch`.

Answer (score 33):

Since git 2.29, released in [october 2020](https://github.com/git/git/blob/v2.29.0/Documentation/RelNotes/2.29.0.txt), you can leverage negative refspec to exclude a specific branch to be fetched.

For GitHub Pages, you can do it like so:

```sh
git config --add remote.origin.fetch '^refs/heads/gh-pages'
```

And Dependabot:

```sh
git config --add remote.origin.fetch '^refs/heads/dependabot/*'
```

You can read more about it on https://github.blog/2020-10-19-git-2-29-released/#user-content-negative-refspecs

Comment: You might want to quote the command as `git config --add remote.origin.fetch '^refs/heads/dependabot/*'`, depending on your shell.

Comment: works like a charm, thanks. i've just added `fetch = ^refs/heads/boring-branch` to `[remote "origin"]` section of my repo `.git/config`.

Answer (score 7):

You can modify the .gitconfig, so it tells `git` to fetch only what you just want:

```
   fetch = +refs/heads/mybranch:refs/remotes/origin/mybranch
```

Also, you can create an alias for the fetch which fetches what you want:

```
 git fetch origin +refs/heads/mybranch:refs/remotes/origin/mybranch
```

The creation of an alias is as simple as adding the new alias in .gitconfig:

```
 [alias]
   myfetch= git fetch origin +refs/heads/mybranch:refs/remotes/origin/mybranch
```

UPDATE:

You can specify more branches of course:

```
 git fetch origin +refs/heads/master:refs/remotes/origin/master +refs/heads/develop:refs/remotes/origin/develop
```

Comment: Is there something that will let me fetch everything *except* what I don't want? In the example above there's only one remote branch I want, but in reality there are several, and it's only one that I don't want.

Comment: @Reid Unfortunatelly, I dont know about direect exlusion of one particular branch. I have at kleast provided an update in the answer, which shows you how to specify more branches which want to be fetched.

Comment: One option might be to use a script hooked to post-receive to delete the offending branch.  Haven't fully thought that through to an answer though.

Answer (score 3):

I just hit the same problem. I was interested in one branch from 'bob', but he had many branches cluttering up my `git branch -a` output.

I did this:

```
rm .git/refs/remotes/bob/{next,master,maint}
```

and the branches were gone. A git fetch might restore them though, but I don't intend to fetch from bob regularly.

Comment: This is the same as `git branch -d -r bob/{next,master,maint}`. The remote tracking branches will indeed return after a subsequent `git fetch`.

Answer (score 0):

If you are adding to remote.origin.fetch a negative refspec, then make sure to use Git 2.38 (Q3 2022): "[`git remote show [-n] frotz`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/33f448b5fc916e6be266b857617a3b27a467da81/Documentation/git-remote.txt#L168-L187)"<sup>([man](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-remote#Documentation/git-remote.txt-emshowem))</sup> now pays attention to negative pathspec.

See [commit 2c80a82](https://github.com/git/git/commit/2c80a82e34311b7363ec99c3034a2f2711704c7f) (16 Jun 2022) by [Jacob Keller (`jacob-keller`)](https://github.com/jacob-keller).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit 33f448b](https://github.com/git/git/commit/33f448b5fc916e6be266b857617a3b27a467da81), 13 Jul 2022)</sup>

> ### [`remote`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/2c80a82e34311b7363ec99c3034a2f2711704c7f): handle negative refspecs in git remote show
>
> <sup>Reported-by: Pavel Rappo</sup>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: Jacob Keller</sup>

> By default, the [`git remote show`]https://github.com/git/git/blob/33f448b5fc916e6be266b857617a3b27a467da81/Documentation/git-remote.txt#L168-L187)<sup>([man](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-remote#Documentation/git-remote.txt-emshowem))</sup> command will query data from remotes to show data about what might be done on a future `git fetch`.
>
> This process currently does not handle negative refspecs.
>
> This can be confusing, because the `show` command will list refs as if they would be fetched.
>
> For example if the fetch refspec "`^refs/heads/pr/*`", it still displays the following:
>
> ```
>  * remote jdk19
>    Fetch URL: git@github.com:openjdk/jdk19.git
>    Push  URL: git@github.com:openjdk/jdk19.git
>    HEAD branch: master
>    Remote branches:
>      master tracked
>      pr/1   new (next fetch will store in remotes/jdk19)
>      pr/2   new (next fetch will store in remotes/jdk19)
>      pr/3   new (next fetch will store in remotes/jdk19)
>    Local ref configured for 'git push':
>      master pushes to master (fast-forwardable)
> ```
>
> Fix this by adding an additional check inside of `get_ref_states`.
> If a ref matches one of the negative refspecs, mark it as skipped instead of marking it as new or tracked.
>
> With this change, we now report remote branches that are skipped due to negative refspecs properly:
>
> ```
>  * remote jdk19
>    Fetch URL: git@github.com:openjdk/jdk19.git
>    Push  URL: git@github.com:openjdk/jdk19.git
>    HEAD branch: master
>    Remote branches:
>      master tracked
>      pr/1   skipped           <=====
>      pr/2   skipped           <=====
>      pr/3   skipped           <=====
>    Local ref configured for 'git push':
>      master pushes to master (fast-forwardable)
> ```
>
> **By showing the refs as `skipped`, it helps clarify that these references won't actually be fetched**.
>
> This does not properly handle refs going stale due to a newly added negative refspec.
> In addition, '`git remote`' prune doesnt handle that negative refspec case either.
> Fixing that requires digging into `get_stale_heads` and handling the case of a ref which exists on the remote but is omitted due to a negative refspec locally.