# How to stop fetching a given branch from a given remote?

Tags: git

I've just added a new remote to my local repository and fetched, now I got all the branches from the new remote fetched. There's one branch I have no interest, and I want to stop fetching it when I do `git fetch <new remote>`.

How do I stop fetching such remote branch?

I've done `git branch -d -r <new remote>/<non-wanted branch>` but I need to do something more to stop refetching it at each `git fetch <new remote>`.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16842426/can-git-permanently-ignore-a-remote-branch for information on how to set up a whitelist of branches. I don't know any way to set up a blacklist, like you want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do not. There is no benefit from *not* fetching them. You get the reference `<remote>/<branch-name>` added, which you can use, if you want, but don't have to. And all the objects are fetched anyway, so there is no performance/storage size improvement.

Just ignore the branches of that remote. Your local branches are not affected by this.

If you didn't know: a remote branch is nothing more than a file at `.git/refs/remotes/<remote-name>/<branch-name>` that contains the commit ID. This file should do you no harm :)

Comment: Well, not quite. I have a similar case where that branch has a huge size (gigabytes), whereas the branch I'm interested in has not. Since I'm tight in space, I'd like avoid fetching all those big objects I'm not interested in. That extra space *does* have harm.

Comment: Given that my org has hundreds or thousands of branches, it's definitely an *organizational* benefit not to have them all showing up in my logs or graphs or autocompletions if they're not descendants of main or things I'm working on

Answer (score 6):

As [opatut noted](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18863348/1256452), there's little if any benefit to "not fetching" the remote's branch references: just don't use the ones you don't care about.

If you have some automated thingy that insists on using them [edit: and want to blacklist certain branches—if you just want to *white*-list, see below], there are two workarounds:

- delete them every time (requires doing something after `git fetch`)
- use the trick described below (also requires doing something after `git fetch`)

A "remote branch" is simply a reference of the form `refs/remotes/rmt/br`, where *`rmt`* is the name of the remote (e.g., `origin`) and *`br`* is the name of the branch (e.g., `master`).  What creates them is this line that you will see in your repo's `.git/config` file (run `git config -e` to bring it up in your editor):

```
fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
```

This tells `git fetch` that it should take all the ref names matching `refs/heads/*` and update them (forcibly, because of the `+` character—otherwise they would be limited to fast-forward updates) but change their name to `refs/remotes/origin/*`, where the `*` part obviously matches.

Thus, if you change this to:

```
fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/real-remotes/origin/*
```

the `git fetch` operation will update (or create if needed) `refs/real-remotes/origin` instead of `refs/remotes/origin`.

You can then do:

```
git for-each-ref refs/real-remotes/origin/
```

to enumerate all these refs (with all the options available in [`git for-each-ref`](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-for-each-ref.html)), and run them through scripts that remove any black-listed ones and update the remaining ones in `refs/remotes/origin/`.  For instance:

```
git for-each-ref refs/real-remotes/origin/ |
while read sha1 reftype refname; do
    shortname=${refname#refs/real-remotes/origin/}
    if [ $shortname != master ]; then
        git update-ref refs/remotes/origin/$shortname $sha1
    fi
done
```

This updates everything *except* `master` (which is a very odd thing to do, but hey, we have just done it).  (Side note: it "hard-links", as it were, a remote ref that is symbolic, e.g., if there's a `HEAD` that is a `ref: ref/remotes/origin/master` this turns it into whatever that would refer to.  Use `git symbolic-ref` to test for such refs, although it's up to you to figure out what to *do* with them, once you find any.)

(The primary difference between this and explicitly deleting some particular remote branch is that this version leaves the remote branch around, without updating it.  For instance, this leaves `origin/master` unmoved; the "real" remote master is now only in `refs/real-remotes/origin/master`.)

[Edit: if you just want to *white* list particular branches, just list them explicitly:

```
fetch = +refs/heads/master:refs/remotes/origin/master
fetch = +refs/heads/devel:refs/remotes/origin/devel
```

Use as many `fetch =` lines as needed.  Note that `git fetch` will error out if the remote no longer has one of these branches, though.]