# Understanding "git remote show" command output... Which is the meaning of: "Local ref configured for 'git push'"?

Tags: git, github, git-branch

I have two remotes and two local branches:

- local branch "master" is tracking remote branch "origin/master"
- local branch "mirror" is tracking remote branch "github/master"

This is in my .git/config file:

```
...

[remote "origin"]
    url = http://my.gitlab.com/nandoquintana/repo.git
    fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
[remote "github"]
    url = https://github.com/nandoquintana/repo.git
    fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/github/*
[branch "master"]
    remote = origin
    merge = refs/heads/master
[branch "mirror"]
    remote = github
    merge = refs/heads/master
[push]
    default = tracking
```

This is the output of "git remote show origin":

```
$ git remote show origin 

* remote origin
  Fetch URL: http://my.gitlab.com/nandoquintana/repo.git
  Push  URL: http://my.gitlab.com/nandoquintana/repo.git
  HEAD branch: master
  Remote branch:
    master tracked
  Local branch configured for 'git pull':
    master merges with remote master
  Local ref configured for 'git push':
    master pushes to master (up to date)

$ git remote show github

* remote github
  Fetch URL: https://github.com/nandoquintana/repo.git
  Push  URL: https://github.com/nandoquintana/repo.git
  HEAD branch: master
  Remote branch:
    master tracked
  Local branch configured for 'git pull':
    mirror merges with remote master
  Local ref configured for 'git push':
    master pushes to master (local out of date)
```

Both "push" and "pull" commands work properly:

- "push" command sends committed edits in a local branch to "her" remote branch.
- "pull" command brings commits from a remote branch to "her" local branch.

So, why "Local ref configured for 'git push'" is "master pushes to master"? why not "mirror pushes to master"? and what does "local out of date" means?

**UPDATED** after @torek answer:

Here we are some refs:

```
$ git ls-remote github
455063a9db09977535ac808af5729181b153f4c7    HEAD
455063a9db09977535ac808af5729181b153f4c7    refs/heads/master

$ cat .git/refs/heads/master
ca9e4399058a4998bd7c993f86d6740cfaec820b
$ cat .git/refs/heads/mirror
455063a9db09977535ac808af5729181b153f4c7
$ cat .git/refs/remotes/github/master
455063a9db09977535ac808af5729181b153f4c7
```

Exactly, "refs/remotes/github/master" and "refs/heads/master" are not equal. That is why "local out of date" message appears:

```
master pushes to master (local out of date)
```

That is not a problem for me, I positively know that code in "remotes/github/master" and in local "master" are different.

Nevertheless, code in "remotes/github/master" and local "mirror" are the same. In fact, refs "refs/remotes/github/master" and "refs/heads/mirror" are equal.

This is the message that would give me some peace of mind:

```
mirror pushes to master (up to date)
```

How could I configure remote/github... or push.default... to get this output?

Comment: What is the exact command you use when pushing changes from your local `mirror` branch?

Comment: Being in mirror branch ("git checkout mirror") simply  "git push".

Comment: Maybe just check all is well with your tracking by re-applying where "mirror" is tracking: `git branch -u github/master` (first checkout mirror). And then run your `git remote show github` command again. Are you sure your pushes are going to the right place?

Comment: @code_fodder thanks for the advice... I'm afraid that after "re-applying", the output is the same... :-( and yes, commits go to the right place :-)

Comment: See also "[Can git permanently ignore a remote branch?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73001754/6309)".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Some reminders, to both myself and OP: remote `origin` = GitLab, remote `github` = GitHub.  Fundamentally, the main problem with using `git remote show` is that it makes *assumptions*.  These assumptions are about how you will run other Git commands—`git fetch` and `git push`—in the future, and about how the second Git repository involved in each of those Git commands will be laid out in the future.  Per, apparently, an [old Danish proverb](https://quoteinvestigator.com/2013/10/20/no-predict/): *It is difficult to make predictions, especially about the future.*]

Let me address the edited question at the top here:

> This is the message that would give me some peace of mind:
>
> ```
> mirror pushes to master (up to date)
> ```
>
> How could I configure remote/github... or push.default... to get this output?

There is one thing that is worth a try: one `push.default` setting, `upstream`, tells Git that by default, `git push` should do this.  if that works and does what you want, you're all set.  But note that whatever Git says here, it's something of a lie anyway.

The fundamental problem is that `mirror` *doesn't* push to `master`.  **Until you enter a `git push` command**, it doesn't push to anything at all; once you do enter that command, *you* control *where* it goes *with* that `git push` command, which can totally override any claim `git remote show` made.

Your options at `git push` time are:

- Supply no additional arguments.

  In this case, your Git picks the *remote* from the current upstream.  If the upstream is set to `origin/...` the remote is `origin`.  If the upstream is set to `github/...` the remote is `github`.  It looks like a simple string substitution (and usually it is, although for historical reasons, it's actually a horribly complicated string substitution that *usually* turns out to be simple: take the part before the slash).

  At this point, your Git proceeds on to the second case listed here.
- Supply one additional argument.  This argument names the other Git to connect to.  It's usually a *remote* (`origin` or `github`), though at this point you can give a URL instead, for instance.
- Supply two or more additional arguments.  The first of these names the remote (or is a URL).  The rest are *refspecs*, as defined below.

At this point, your Git connects to that remote and, in effect, runs `git ls-remote` to see what branches they have.  This list is important because it's used with the refspecs you gave, or failed to give, based on your `push.default` setting, and the fact that when you *do* give a refspec, you can give just *half* a refspec.

It's the "half a refspec" case that's particularly problematic.  No matter what else you do or set, if you actually run `git push github mirror` while you're on `mirror`, your Git will ask the Git on remote `github` to set ... well, this depends on whether you have an upstream set for it, and if not, your `push.default` setting.  The details are in [the `git push` documentation](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-push.html), in Git's usual cryptic form.  The *default* default, though, is that for a "half refspec", the name `mirror` means `mirror:mirror`.

If you give a full refspec, e.g., `git push github mirror:asdf`, the second half of the refspec determines which branch name your Git asks their Git to set.  If you give half a refspec, the half you gave usually becomes both names.  With the default of `push.default = simple`, you can't accidentally push your `mirror` to *anyone* else's `master`, you must use the explicit full refspec (and then it's up to you to get it right).

If you give *no* refspec, your Git falls back on `push.default`, and there are only five settings for it.  The default one, `simple`, has your Git compare your set of branches to their set of branches (from `git ls-remote`).  If your branch, such as `mirror`, *doesn't* have any corresponding branch there, your Git won't ask their Git to set *any* branches.

Let's assume you are on your branch `mirror`, which has its upstream set to `github/master`, and that you have configured `push.default` to `upstream` (using `git config push.default upstream`):

- If you run `git push` with no arguments, or `git push github` with no additional arguments, the *remote* will be `github`.
- If you supply no refspec, the `push.default` setting applies: the refspec Git will construct will be `mirror:master`.
- However, if you supply half a refspec, I'm not sure, even after re-reading the documentation several times, what *full* refspec Git will construct.  I *think* it will be `mirror:mirror`, which is not what you want.
- You can also configure a `remote.github.push` variable that supplies default refspecs.  This might also allow you to get what you want, although `push.default = upstream` seems simpler.

We now return to the original answer. :-)

---

> So, why "Local ref configured for 'git push'" is "master pushes to master"?

This means that:

- assuming your current branch is `master` (i.e., you have run `git checkout master`)
- and if you then run `git push github` (*not* `git push github more-command-words`)
- Git—specifically *your own* Git—will attempt to push your current `master` to `https://github.com/nandoquintana/repo.git`'s `master`

which may or may not succeed, depending on what the Git server at GitHub does with a polite request to set *its* `master` to whatever hash ID your Git sends with this push request.

(The same holds if you're on `master` and run `git push origin`, again with no additional arguments, except that the name `origin` refers to the Git at GitLab.)

On the other hand, let's assume your current branch is named `mirror`:

- so you just ran `git checkout mirror`
- and now you run `git push github`
- your Git will—based on what it sees right now, hence assuming this is what it sees again—*not* attempt to push *anything*.

The reason for this is most likely that you have `push.default` configured, or defaulted, to `simple`.  When `push.default` is set to `simple`, a `git push` without a *refspec* argument tries to push the *current* branch, but *only if the other Git has a branch with the same name*.  So if the Git at `github` (i.e., at `https://github.com/...`) still does not *have* a branch named `mirror`, your Git will say to itself: *Huh.  No branch named `mirror`.  Better not push anything.*

(If, tomorrow, that other Git on GitHub *does* have a branch named `mirror`, your Git will say to itself: *Aha!  There's the branch named `mirror`!  OK, I'll ask that other Git to update its `mirror`.*)

> why not "mirror pushes to master"?

Because it doesn't.  Even if you re-configure your `push.default`, there's no default setting that means "if I fail to give `git push` a refspec, make a non-matching one up."

#### A brief segment on refspecs

All of this is keyed on the concept of a *refspec*.  In Git, a refspec is essentially a *pair of references*.

A *reference* is the fancy word for "branch or tag name".  (It can be more than just those two, but those are the main two.)  A branch name like `master` is short-hand for its full spelling, `refs/heads/master`.  This *reference* name, `refs/heads/master`, is Git's way to say "not just `master`, but the *branch* `master`".  A short tag name like `v1.2` is short-hand for the reference name `refs/tags/v1.2`.  If you leave out the `refs/heads/` or `refs/tags/` part, Git usually figures out which one you mean by looking at the branches and tags you have now.

Anyway, a *refspec* is mostly just *two* of these things with a colon `:` in the middle:

```
refs/heads/master:refs/heads/master
```

for instance.  You need two of them because you are using two Gits: one on your system, which you ask to do something, plus another one on some *remote*, such as `gitlab` or `github`.  You have your Git call up the other Git over the Internet-phone.  Then your Git and their Git talk to each other, after which your Git will *fetch* or *push* things.

The fetch and push steps need one reference for each Git, so that means you need *two* references: a refspec.

The two halves of a refspec are the *source* and the *destination*.  If you're running `git fetch`, the source is the *other* Git and the destination is your own Git.  If you are running `git push`, *you* are the source; the other Git becomes the destination.  But in either case, the source gives some commits to the destination, and then the source's *name*—the left half of the refspec—is used to change something in the destination's *name*—the right half of the refspec.

For `git fetch`, it's entirely normal to have a different name on each side.  We *fetch from* their `refs/heads/master` and *write to* our own `refs/remotes/origin/master`.  We fetch from their `refs/heads/master` and write to our own `refs/remotes/mirror/master`.  This lets us fetch from a bunch of different places, yet keep them all straight.

For `git push`, though, it's much more normal to use the *same* name on each side.  We fetch from their `master`, into our `refs/remotes/.../master`.  Then we work for a while and make sure whatever is in *our* `master` is an update that goes on top of their `master`, by merging or rebasing for instance.  Then we call them up again, deliver our new commits, and ask them to set their `master`—not their `nando/master`, which they don't even have, but their `master`—to this latest commit that builds upon their previous commits.

We make sure that it builds upon theirs, by fetching first, then working, then pushing.  If we lose a "race" with Sofia—we both fetch about the same time, but she works faster and then she pushes before we can—we get that "remote rejected" "not fast forward" error; we must fetch again, to pick up Sofia's work from GitHub or wherever, and make our work build atop her work, and then try the push again.

> and what does "local out of date" means?

When your `git remote show` called up the remote—specifically `github`, i.e., `https://github.com/nandoquintana/repo.git`—over the Internet-phone, that *other* Git said:

```
I have these references:
  refs/heads/master  <some big ugly hash ID>
```

(try running `git ls-remote github` to see what they have, you will get the complete list).

Your own Git has a branch named `master`, but the big ugly hash ID *your* Git has for *your* `refs/heads/master`—your `master` branch—is different.

Since the two are different, your Git assumes you are either "ahead"—you have some commits they don't—or "behind" (they have some commits you don't), or perhaps both.  Your Git can't tell how *far* behind you are, if you are behind at all, but it *can* tell how far "ahead" you are, by looking at all your commits.  If you have commit `129bca4f...` whose parent is `e033fc12...`, and *they* are at commit `e033fc12...`, then you're ahead by just one commit.

If your Git can find their Git's commit hash ID in your `master` branch's history, you are "ahead" and you can probably `git push` right now to send them your new commits, asking them to set their `master` to `129bca4f...`, and they will probably take the commits and update their `master`.

But if they have commit `930ab988...` and you *don't* have that commit at all, all your Git knows is that they have some commits you don't.  You must be "behind".  You can `git fetch` from them, get all the commits they have that you don't, and remember them with `refs/remotes/github/master`.  You can then do whatever it takes to *add* those commits to your own `master`, so that you are even with them—neither ahead nor behind—and do any additional work it takes so that you are now *ahead of* them.

It's up to you to decide whether that's a good idea, and if so, whether to do it.  All `git remote show` does is call them up, using `git ls-remote`, over the Internet-phone, and compare their references to your references to guess what `git fetch` and `git push` would do, based on those results.  (If you use `git pull`, that just means *run `git fetch`, then run `git merge`*.  The `git remote show` command tries to guess what that will do, too.)

Comment: Thank you very much for the explanations about refspecs and so.

Comment: I have updated my questions with comments about your answer

Comment: I think you have written remotes/mirror when you meant remotes/github :-(

Comment: That's possible - it's hard to keep the names straight.  Let me go through this again...

Comment: BTW, see also https://stackoverflow.com/q/45984929/1256452 - if you have some upstream set and have `push.default` set to `upstream` and run `git push <remote>`, the `upstream` setting appears to propagate through, even though you've overridden the default *remote*. So be careful if you do set `push.default` to `upstream`.

Comment: Thanks for the update and thanks again for the wide explanations. I see how tricky could be the use (or not) of push params... Now I understand a bit more deeply "push" operation :-)