# Git behavior when upstream is different than given repository

Tags: git

I wonder if the below described behavuour is bug or works as desugm anyhow i cant find support for it in git documents.

lets assume

```
# git version is 2.13.3
#Local repository has two remotes origin and dev
git push -u origin br6:br6ups # "Branch br6 set up to track remote branch br6ups from origin."
#assume push.defualt is upstream
#what is the expected behavior ?
git push dev br6
```

Well, the upstream is origin/br6ups, but git pushs to dev/br6ups

it seems that GIT ignores 'branch.br6.remote' and uses only 'branch.br6.merge'

1. Is this is valid behavior ?
2. Shouldn't GIT protect me pushing to different repository ?
3. Can any one direct me to some document that describes this behavior ?

Thanks
Boaz

Answer (score 0):

No, git should not "protect you" from pushing to a different repository.  The config settings are defaults; you specified via command line options that you wanted to push to a different remote (so then git just used config to figure out the default refspec rules for pushing to that remote).

The range of push behaviors (e.g. which config settings are used in what order, which command line arguments override which config settings, etc.) is described here: https://git-scm.com/docs/git-push

Comment: The `git push` documentation also links to `git config`, and one has to look at both manual pages for some corner cases. The result is ... well, *I* find it confusing, at least. :-)